# TSAI PatchTST - how to train with input and output of different sizes?

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series

I am using this template for time series forecasting
https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/blob/main/tutorial_nbs/15_PatchTST_a_new_transformer_for_LTSF.ipynb

I would like to predict a subset of the time series columns

I tried to change this:

```
x_vars = df.columns[1:]
y_vars = df.columns[1:]
```

to this:

```
x_vars = df[['feature 1', 'feature 2', 'feature 3', 'feature 4', 'feature 5', 'feature 6']]
y_vars = df[['feature 4']]
```

but it looks like is not enough, I get the following error. Any insight?:

```
'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 6
      4 n_epochs = 100
      5 lr_max = 0.0025
----> 6 learn.fit_one_cycle(n_epochs, lr_max=lr_max)
      7 learn.export('patchTST.pt')

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\callback\schedule.py:119, in fit_one_cycle(self, n_epoch, lr_max, div, div_final, pct_start, wd, moms, cbs, reset_opt, start_epoch)
    116 lr_max = np.array([h['lr'] for h in self.opt.hypers])
    117 scheds = {'lr': combined_cos(pct_start, lr_max/div, lr_max, lr_max/div_final),
    118           'mom': combined_cos(pct_start, *(self.moms if moms is None else moms))}
--> 119 self.fit(n_epoch, cbs=ParamScheduler(scheds)+L(cbs), reset_opt=reset_opt, wd=wd, start_epoch=start_epoch)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:264, in Learner.fit(self, n_epoch, lr, wd, cbs, reset_opt, start_epoch)
    262 self.opt.set_hypers(lr=self.lr if lr is None else lr)
    263 self.n_epoch = n_epoch
--> 264 self._with_events(self._do_fit, 'fit', CancelFitException, self._end_cleanup)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:253, in Learner._do_fit(self)
    251 for epoch in range(self.n_epoch):
    252     self.epoch=epoch
--> 253     self._with_events(self._do_epoch, 'epoch', CancelEpochException)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:247, in Learner._do_epoch(self)
    246 def _do_epoch(self):
--> 247     self._do_epoch_train()
    248     self._do_epoch_validate()

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:239, in Learner._do_epoch_train(self)
    237 def _do_epoch_train(self):
    238     self.dl = self.dls.train
--> 239     self._with_events(self.all_batches, 'train', CancelTrainException)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:205, in Learner.all_batches(self)
    203 def all_batches(self):
    204     self.n_iter = len(self.dl)
--> 205     for o in enumerate(self.dl): self.one_batch(*o)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\tsai\learner.py:40, in one_batch(self, i, b)
     38 b_on_device = to_device(b, device=self.dls.device) if self.dls.device is not None else b
     39 self._split(b_on_device)
---> 40 self._with_events(self._do_one_batch, 'batch', CancelBatchException)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:219, in Learner._do_one_batch(self)
    217 self('after_pred')
    218 if len(self.yb):
--> 219     self.loss_grad = self.loss_func(self.pred, *self.yb)
    220     self.loss = self.loss_grad.clone()
    221 self('after_loss')

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\losses.py:54, in BaseLoss.__call__(self, inp, targ, **kwargs)
     52 if targ.dtype in [torch.int8, torch.int16, torch.int32]: targ = targ.long()
     53 if self.flatten: inp = inp.view(-1,inp.shape[-1]) if self.is_2d else inp.view(-1)
---> 54 return self.func.__call__(inp, targ.view(-1) if self.flatten else targ, **kwargs)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:535, in MSELoss.forward(self, input, target)
    534 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 535     return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3315, in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   3308 r"""mse_loss(input, target, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction='mean') -> Tensor
   3309 
   3310 Measures the element-wise mean squared error.
   3311 
   3312 See :class:`~torch.nn.MSELoss` for details.
   3313 """
   3314 if has_torch_function_variadic(input, target):
-> 3315     return handle_torch_function(
   3316         mse_loss, (input, target), input, target, size_average=size_average, reduce=reduce, reduction=reduction
   3317     )
   3318 if not (target.size() == input.size()):
   3319     warnings.warn(
   3320         f"Using a target size ({target.size()}) that is different to the input size ({input.size()}). "
   3321         "This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. "
   3322         "Please ensure they have the same size.",
   3323         stacklevel=2,
   3324     )

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\overrides.py:1577, in handle_torch_function(public_api, relevant_args, *args, **kwargs)
   1571     warnings.warn("Defining your `__torch_function__ as a plain method is deprecated and "
   1572                   "will be an error in future, please define it as a classmethod.",
   1573                   DeprecationWarning)
   1575 # Use `public_api` instead of `implementation` so __torch_function__
   1576 # implementations can do equality/identity comparisons.
-> 1577 result = torch_func_method(public_api, types, args, kwargs)
   1579 if result is not NotImplemented:
   1580     return result

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\fastai\torch_core.py:382, in TensorBase.__torch_function__(cls, func, types, args, kwargs)
    380 if cls.debug and func.__name__ not in ('__str__','__repr__'): print(func, types, args, kwargs)
    381 if _torch_handled(args, cls._opt, func): types = (torch.Tensor,)
--> 382 res = super().__torch_function__(func, types, args, ifnone(kwargs, {}))
    383 dict_objs = _find_args(args) if args else _find_args(list(kwargs.values()))
    384 if issubclass(type(res),TensorBase) and dict_objs: res.set_meta(dict_objs[0],as_copy=True)

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py:1386, in Tensor.__torch_function__(cls, func, types, args, kwargs)
   1383     return NotImplemented
   1385 with _C.DisableTorchFunctionSubclass():
-> 1386     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1387     if func in get_default_nowrap_functions():
   1388         return ret

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3328, in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   3325 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3326     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3328 expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
   3329 return torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))

File ~\.conda\envs\tsai\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:73, in broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
     71 if has_torch_function(tensors):
     72     return handle_torch_function(broadcast_tensors, tensors, *tensors)
---> 73 return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (672) must match the size of tensor b (112) at non-singleton dimension 0
'''
```